# Eager compilation with Numba slower than automatic type inference?

Tags: python, numba

I am experimenting with `numba` currently and I just tried [one of their example notebooks](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Using%20Numba.ipynb) about `jit` compilation. I noticed that the eager compilation when giving types was slower than the compilation without types. The function they have been given was:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, autojit

def looped_ver(k, a):
    x = np.empty_like(a)
    x[0] = 0.0
    for i in range(1, x.size):
        sm = 0.0
        for j in range(0, i):
            sm += k[i-j,j] * a[i-j] * a[j]
        x[i] = sm
    return x

typed_ver = jit('f8[:](f8[:,:],f8[:])')(looped_ver)
auto_ver = autojit(looped_ver)
```

I measured the execution time with

```
for n in [200,500,1000]:
    k = np.random.rand(n,n)
    a = np.random.rand(n)
    %timeit typed_ver(k, a)
    %timeit auto_ver(k, a)
```

The results are:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.2 µs per loop

10000 loops, best of 3: 168 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 152 µs per loop

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
```

Which seems strange the `typed` version is slower than the untyped one. After inspecting the compiled code and there was no difference, except that the inferred type for the `typed` one was in `A` order and the `untyped` in `C` order.

I am using Numba 0.23.1, Numpy 1.10.1, Python 3.5.1 on Windows10.

How can I setup the `typed` version that it is as fast as the untyped one? Or is that not possible?

Comment: What version of numba are you using? I don't see nearly the difference you're reporting using 0.23.1 on OSX (N:  200 - 27.8 µs per loop / 28 µs per loop); (N:  500 -  211 µs per loop / 216 µs per loop); and  (N:  1000 - 1.21 ms per loop / 1.21 ms per loop). So the timings are almost nearly identical or the autojit version is slightly slower.

Comment: In the past I've seen pretty similar results on my own programs. At a guess this would be roughly around Numba 0.18. I haven't reinvestigated with a recent version though. So you aren't going mad, but I can't offer a much advice to help.

Comment: @JoshAdel - I've added the versions to the question.

Comment: did you look a difference in performance of c-order with fortran-order array types, since you have nested looping?

Comment: @denfromufa A short test shows that `F-order-arrays` have the same pattern: Eager as fast as with C-order; autotyped a bit faster than autotyped with C-order. So the loops are probably more F-friendly... but almost neglectable